# About usage of prepositions

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I've recently seen this sentence in an article:

Robert is an authority on English literature.

Could you explain why there is used preposition "on" with a noun "authority", but with adjective "good" we use "at"?

Robert is good at English literature.

Comment: Are you sure you've phrased the first example sentence correctly?

Comment: Explaining why is not important. Suffice to say that each verb that uses prepositions has found its own that work for each set of circumstances, and that you just have to learn them when you learn the verbs.

Comment: The specific preposition to use isn't always set in stone. I'd probably usually say *good **at** [subject*, but I can't see anything unusual about *"When we play Trivial Pursuit I'm good **on** Science & Nature [questions], but I dread Sports & Leisure"*.

Comment: @Robusto is absolutely right. Some prepositions sometimes have a meaning, but most of them are governed by the verb or noun they appear with, and the combinations are essentially arbitrary and must be learned individually, just like English spellings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Longman's DCE has "authority on sth" in no. 4

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/authority

Sometimes you have to look up the preposition that follows a noun. I would put this use of "on" to the group "on + topic/subject" as in:

- an article/a comment/a pamphlet/ discussions on a special topic. You can't conclude that "at" as in "good at an activity" can also be applied after "authority".